Flutter - Jump to Pageview at specific index not working when data is reloaded in the beginning of the list
I am working on a flutter app, I have a horizontal pageView that can be swiped left and right. I have implemented pagination so that when the user reaches to the top of the list(swipe left) data is fetched from the server and appended in the beginning and when the user reaches to the end of the list (swipe right) the data is fetch from the server and appended at the end of the list. This is where I am seeing the issue -

Initially I have 4 dataItems. Current page is set to 4.

user swipes left and reaches to the second last index.

server call is made to fetch data.

In SetState{}, New list is added to the existing one at the beginning.

Because the list is updated, the current page that was shown has new index, I am calcualting the new Index and making a call on pageController to jumpTo new page on that index.

Page jumps to the right index, in my case the current page index is 8 and in the app I see the 8th page showing up. But, In the logs after it jumps to page 8, current page changes to Page 4. I am having a hard time figuring out why the page is changing to number 4.

Initialize page controller -


_controller = PageController(initialPage: currentPage);
    _controller.addListener(() {
    if (_controller.page != null) {
      currentPage = _controller.page!.round();
      print('CURRENT PAGE $currentPage');
    }
  }


Method to get data from server and add to the existing list.

Future\<void\> refreshData(int page) async

   {
   //Capture currentItem before updating dataItems
   var currentItem = dataItems\[currentIndex\];
   await widget.chartViewManagerInterface
   ?.refreshData(dataItems, page, currentSegment, isRefreshingData,
   (items, appendAtEnd) {  
   isRefreshingData = false;   // Reset the flag when data is refreshed

   //print('isRefreshingData false');  
   if (items != null) {.
   setState(() {.
   if (appendAtEnd) {.
   dataItems.addAll(items);  
   } else {.
   // Insert at the beginning of the list.  
   dataItems.insertAll(0, items);  
   }.
   var newIndex = dataItems.indexOf(currentItem);  
   if (newIndex != -1) {  
   if (appendAtEnd) {.
   //jump to next page of the currentItem.
   newIndex = newIndex + 1;  
   if (newIndex \< dataItems.length) {.
   print('jump to next page newIndex $newIndex');  
   reload(newIndex);  
   }.
   } else {.
   //jump to previous page of the currentItem.  
   newIndex = newIndex - 1;  
   if (newIndex \>= 0) {.
   print('jump to previous page newIndex $newIndex');  
   reload(newIndex);  
   }.
   }.
   } else {.
   // Optional: Handle the case where currentItem is not found in the updated list
   // For example, jump to the first page or stay at the current page.
   reload(currentIndex);  
   }.
   });  
   }
   });
   }


Reload -

void reload(int index) {.
   debugLog('reload() dataItems count ${dataItems.length} and jumpToPage $index');  
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((\_) {.
   if (\_controller.hasClients) {.
   \_controller.jumpToPage(index);  
   }
   });  
   }


In

Widget build(BuildContext context) {.
   child: PageView.builder(.
   controller: \_controller,  
   onPageChanged: (value) {.
   debugLog('onPageChanged $value');  
   pageChanged(value);  
   setState(() {
   currentIndex = value;  
   });
   },
   itemCount: dataItems.length,  
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
   //currentIndex = index;  
   return \_buildChartPage(index);  
   },
   ),
   ),
   }

Here are the logs

Initially when the page loaded, I have 4 data Items. Current page is 4
Swipe left, current page changed to 3.
CURRENT PAGE 4
onPageChanged 4
page Changed visibleDate: 2024-07-22 00:00:00.000
CURRENT PAGE 4
CURRENT PAGE 3
onPageChanged 3
page Changed visibleDate: 2024-07-21 00:00:00.000
One more Swipe Leftt, Current page changed to 2
same logs
Current page changed to 1 on the next swipe left
onPageChanged 1
page Changed visibleDate: 2021-12-31 00:00:00.000
CURRENT PAGE 1
This is when data items are fetched from server and added to the existing list.
reload() dataItems count 17 and jumpToPage 8
jump to previous page newIndex 8
After jumping to the correct index, I see the logs message where current page is changed.
In the UI it doesnt jump to the Page4
I/flutter ( 6037): CURRENT PAGE 4
onPageChanged 4
page Changed visibleDate: 2017-12-31 00:00:00.000

I am keeping track of a var named visibleDate to do some calculation when the page is changed. and since the page is changed my calculation is messing up.
Note: If I swipe one more left the current page goes back to Page 7, which is expected behavior. Only when the reload happens it messes up. It is definitely to do with PageView not aware of total item count but how do I fix this issue. Any help is appreciated
